# angular is not defined in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have created an out-of-the box cordova app in Visual Studio 2015, then i added AngularJS.Core library using NuGet Manager.

After referencing the angular.js file in my html file, and tried to run the project i keep getting this error:

angular is not defined

here is a sample of my html page:

Hello, your application is ready!

```
<div ng-app="module1" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <p>{{Test}}</p>
</div>

<script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js" ></script>

<script src="scripts/modules/module1/controllers.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resolution for this issue is the following. You should not reference any files outside www folder in any Cordova project app.

All **JS** libraries added using Visual Studio NuGet package manager are added under **Scripts** folder outside www, which is not helpful in case of Cordova apps. To allow Cordova app to access **JS** files, copy any required libraries from the Scripts folder to any location under the www folder.

For example: "www-->scripts" as per your project structure and it will work!

Hope this helps.

**PS**: Same applies to **Fonts**, and **Stylesheets**.

Comment: Thanks, I did make some grammatical change to you answer.

Comment: Hi, Do you know then the meaning of having those folders :  Scripts, Fonts Stylesheets outside www. Is there a possibility to synchonize the content of those folders with the corresponding content in www? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can do through Cordova Hooks, so you can sync these files everytime you hit f5.  Check out my answer in MSDN:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1a1eecec-ab16-43b3-a21c-025d30545924/how-to-copy-nuget-packages-scripts-folder-into-www-folder?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova