# VS2105 - my first apache Cordova apps - references issue

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

My issue is: 
The references are not found when I lunch the app in the Android simulator.

Here what I did in my project solution after I created the project from the BlankCrodovaApp template.

Did add Bootstrap using NuGet packager manager.

[image: vs2015 solution explorer]

Did add the scr in the Index.html file.

```
<!-- References BlankCordovaApp1 -->
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery-1.9.1.min.js (0,0)
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
bootstrap.min.js (0,0)
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
bootstrap.min.css (0,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found  this on StackOverFlow

The resolution for this issue is the following. You should not reference any files outside www folder in any Cordova project app.

All JS libraries added using Visual Studio NuGet package manager are added under Scripts folder outside www, which is not helpful in case of Cordova apps. To allow Cordova app to access JS files, copy any required libraries from the Scripts folder to any location under the www folder.

The complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393816/angular-is-not-defined-in-visual-studio-2015)